# http request response not in json format

Tags: python, json, http, request, response

I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this but still no luck. appreciate if you could help.

This is in Python

**When I run this:**

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.post(url)
response.text
```

**I get this:**

> '\n\n\n\n{\nVisitCount : "9,992",\ntotalCount : "18,018",\nnotiList :
> [\n\n],\nPassed : false\n}'

**If I run this:**

```
print(response.text)
```

**I get this:**

> { VisitCount : "9,992", totalCount : "18,018,455", notiList : [
>
> ], Passed : false }

Ultimately I am aiming for extracting the number 9,992. **I thought easiest way is to convert this into json, but it doesn't seem to work.**

**When I run:**

```
response.json() or json.loads(response.text)
```

**I get this:**

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
> line 6 column 1 (char 6)

Which is probably because it's missing the double quotes in the response.

1. how can I fix this problem, probably adding double quotes to the response?
2. is there an easier way of extracting the number, which in this case is 9,992?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexes:

```
import re
number_string = re.findall("VisitCount\W+:\W+.*?([0-9,]+).*", response.text.strip())[0]
```

gives `number_string` as

```
9,992
```

If you want to convert it into `int`:

```
number = int(number_string.replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it.